# C# Serial port send and wait for recieve

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have some commands that I stored into list. I need to go thrue list, send command and wait a reply for specific time (time is also in the list).

This is my code:

```
SerialPort myPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

bool _doSend;
string _inSensor;
int _threadWait;

Thread myThread = new Thread(myStartingMethod);

checkPortStatus();

private void checkPortStatus()
{
    if (!(myPort.IsOpen == true))
        {
            myPort.Open();
            myPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(myPort_DataReceived);
            _doSend = true;
            myThread.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            _doSend = false;
            myPort.Close();
            myThread.Abort();
        }
}

public void myStartingMethod()
    {
        //Create list of commands
        List<List<String>> atCommands = new List<List<string>>();

        //Create list of time to wait for informaition (recieve on setial port)
        List<List<String>> thSleep = new List<List<string>>();

        thSleep.Add(new List<string> { "1", "1000" }); //{"Sensor ID", "Time to wait for replay"}
        thSleep.Add(new List<string> { "2", "5000" });

        atCommands.Add(new List<string> { "1", "A111", "B111"});  //{"Sensor ID", "command 1", "command 2"}
        atCommands.Add(new List<string> { "2", "C222", "D222"});
        atCommands.Add(new List<string> { "1", "A111", "B111", "E111", "F111"});  
        atCommands.Add(new List<string> { "2", "D111"});

        while(_doSend)
        {
            foreach (var _subList in thSleep)
            {
                _inSensor = _subList.ElementAt(0);
                _threadWait = Convert.ToInt32(_subList.ElementAt(1));

                foreach(var subCommands in atCommands)
                {
                     if(_inSensor == subCommand.AlementAt(0)
                     {
                        foreach (string command in subCommands.Skip(1))
                        {
                            myPort.Write(command + "\r\n");

                            Thread.Sleep(_threadWait);
                        }
                     }
                }
            }

        }
    }
void myPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something with data and save to Database
    }
```

My question is: How to be 100% sure that I got reply on command that I sent. If there is no reply within the given time I need to go on other command. In "myPort_DataReceived" I would like to store last sent command and recieved data to mySql database.
I know how to connect to database but I have a problem with wait for response.

Comment: Do you have control on modifying command and response and encapsulating them into objects?

Comment: For this scenario synchrnonous `SerialPort.Read` method with timeout is more appropriate.

Comment: `DataReceived` event is better to use for more complicated communication protocols, when data may be received at any time (for example, kind of interrupt or event notification). For simple "Send - wait for reply" protocol synchronous read is OK.

Comment: Yes, I have Send - wait. But I didn't understand how to send command and put "sender to sleep" and wait for reply x sec. Can you provide some pseudo code?

Comment: port.Write(...); port.ReadTimeout = ...; port.Read(...);

Comment: @AlexFarber I tried your suggest but without success. In last foreach loop `foreach (string command in subCommands.Skip(1))` I catch current command and store it in public string `_currentCommand = command;` When I recieve data I write `_currentCommand + myPort.Read` and in `_currentCommand` I got previous command.

I can send you all solution zipped to email and if you have a time you can check it localy and modified it?